# Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I have hosted a webapp on a linux server using django-uwsgi,I was trying to directly call the --ini file from uwsgi as `uwsgi --ini .ini file` but I'm getting a weird error like this.

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/sites/salesproject.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Tue May 19 23:37:24 2020] ***
compiled with version: 9.3.0 on 18 May 2020 16:02:04
os: Linux-5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020
nodename: django-server
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/uwsgi
detected binary path: /home/ubaid/.local/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /home/ubaid/salesproject
your processes number limit is 15402
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/uwsgi/salesproject.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34)  [GCC 9.3.0]
!!! Python Home is not a directory: /home/ubaid/Env/salesproject !!!
Set PythonHome to /home/ubaid/Env/salesproject
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject'
  sys.executable = '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject/lib/python38.zip',
    '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject/lib/python3.8',
    '/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f966c94e680 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
VACUUM: unix socket /var/uwsgi/salesproject.sock removed.
```

Salesproject is my webapp and I definetly don't have a path like this `/home/ubaid/Env/salesproject`,
my path is like this `/home/ubaid/salesproject`,

Can you please help me resolve this? And yeah I have python3 installed

Comment: what is content of your ini file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Python error: init\_fs\_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding, when trying to start uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184937/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-file)